# Table indexed based on a SubStr needs to be parameterized

Tags: c#, sqlite, indexing

I'm using SQLite from `System.Data.SQLite` in Visual Studio 2017 with C#. My table is indexed on a substring of a column:

```
create index s01 on MyTable (SubStr(MyString, 1, 5))
```

Select using this index might look like :

```
Select * from MyTable where SubStr(MyString, 1, 5) = 'abcde' ;
```

This works until I attempt to parametrize the second parameter to function SubStr. SQLite does not make the substitution:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Select * from MyTable where SubStr( MyString, @param1 , 5) =  'abcde' ;  ";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", System.Data.DbType.Int32);
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = 1;
SQLiteDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The ExecuteReader function doesn't return. I assume because the database is about 35 GB and without an index it is probably scanning the entire database. I have not let it run to completion because it might take hours. Using an index, the database is very fast (as is to be expected).

Why parametrizing a function's parameter in a query string doesn't work? Workarounds are appreciated.

Comment: There is no possible way to optimize that query as it is not a prefix search. You could have changed your original query to use `LIKE` with a prefix, which would have been very efficient, eg `where MyString LIKE 'abcde%'` but your new query wants to find the text anywhere in the string, which cannot be indexed. See also https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search which gives a workaround which may work for you

Comment: Charlieface. The index itself works fine. It is NOT attempting to find the text anywhere in the string, as you say, but it's indexed for that particular substring at the specified location. That's how the index was created. Notice how the sqlite substr function is specifically asking for the first five characters (it's one-based, by the way). So, again, the index itself works fine. My problem has to do with parameterizing the substr function within a query, as my example shows. Doing so doesn't work. The parameter doesn't get replaced with the value I set.

Comment: Of course it works, it's just the server getting bogged down scanning 35GB of data because it has no index, so it doesn't finish in a reasonable time. The index simply doesn't match the query, it cannot be used. Note that even if you pass the parameter value `1` it won't help because the query plan needs to work for all parameter values. Hence why I said it is searching anywhere: you can pass any value to the parameter and therefore search anywhere in the string.

Comment: Charlieface. Thanks, but you are missing the point of my question.  The index works fine. I've edited my question above to show the 'Create Index' command I used to make my question clearer.  It returns results within one second. Again, my question has to do with parameterizing the substr function within the query, not about the index  itself, which is fine.

Comment: What happens when you run static query such as `Select * from MyTable where SubStr( MyString, 3 , 5) =  'abcde' ` ? does it return the result?

Comment: Chetan, No, because I haven't created a specific index for that one. I could though.

Comment: That is *exactly* my point, you don't have an index for the parameterized query, so it's having to scan the whole table. I understand you have an index, but that index doesn't work for this query, it only works for the first query.

Comment: The query is compiled *before* parameters are bound, and there's no way for the bytecode compiler and optimizer to know that you're going to bind the one value that lets it use that index.